# does datepicker in android for year BC and AD exist

Tags: android, datepicker

is there any datepicker in Android, which I can use for selecting dates BC and AD ?
or do I have to create my own one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default datepicker in Android only goes to 1970.

You can somewhat [manipulate the date](http://kevsaidwhat.blogspot.com/2011/10/fun-with-android-datepicker-and-1970.html) though.

For help with creating a custom datepicker, you can try [here](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html).